# I don't get emails when sending by Mandrill NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, mandrill

I have this function below which allows me to send a mail with mandrill nodeJS API :

```
var mandrill = require('mandrill-api/mandrill');
var mandrill_client = new mandrill.Mandrill(config.values.mandrill_api_key);
exports.sendMail = function(htmlContent, textContent, subject, from_email, from_name, to_email, to_name ,reply_to_email, callback) {
    var message = {
        "html": htmlContent,
        "text": textContent,
        "subject": subject,
        "from_email": from_email,
        "from_name": from_name,
        "to": [{
            "email": to_email,
            "name": to_name,
            "type": "to"
        }],
        "headers": {
            "Reply-To": reply_to_email
        },
        "important": false
    };

    var async = false;

    mandrill_client.messages.send({"message": message, "async": async}, function(result) {
        console.log(result);

        callback(result);

    }, function(e) {
        console.log('A mandrill error occurred: ' + e.name + ' - ' + e.message);
    });

};
```

On the mandrill console (https://mandrillapp.com/activity) I can see that emails have been successfully sent (status: Delivered).

**But I don't get it in my gmail box nor hotmail box.**

How to resolve this problem ?

Thanks,

Comment: do a reverse dns lookup, maybe you are being blocked and also try to add the server ip in the whitelist for smtp senders I don't think that  issue should be related to your code at all.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure, you're not using a testing API Key.

> You can use a test key to experiment with Mandrill's API. No mail is actually sent, but webhooks trigger normally and you can generate synthetic bounces and complaints without impacting your reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.

I had to add special fields into my DNS zone : DKIM and SPF

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/22030056-how-do-i-add-dns-records-for-my-sending-domains